# set screen orientation, width and height with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Is it possible to manually set the screen properties of a dynamically generated iframe? would like to set orientation, width and height in order to simulate a "mobile" view for that iframe?

I have created two separate fiddles :

The parent : https://jsfiddle.net/mooioom/69240vec/

The "device" : https://jsfiddle.net/mooioom/19tsk4L8/

1. the parent is opening an iframe pointing to the "device" with iphone resolution dimension 375x667
2. the "device" has a media query to match iphone resolution, and should change the button color from green to yellow if detected, which doesn't happen, probably because the detected `screen.width` and `screen.height` dimensions.

so how can i set `screen.width` and `screen.height` of the "device" at creation time from the parent.

**--- update ---**

so like Gezzasa stated, if media query `min-device-width` is changed to `min-width` it works, but in order to get a complete solution I still would like know how to make the iframe "believe" that it is running inside a mobile device, I have read in a post that it involves modifying the headers and user-agent because some responsive techniques target the user-agent to check if its mobile.

that put aside, the question still stands, how to dynamically set the `screen.width` and `screen.height` (and orientation) for an iframe, from a parent window

Comment: Are you able to edit the content of the iframe? Think simple media queries on the specific page would accomplish that.

Comment: I can edit the content, and I am using mobile media queries inside the iframe. which dimensions are set to fit the mobile pixel dimensions, the problem is that the `screen.width` `screen.height` inside the iframe. is reflecting the real screen which I am using, which is a desktop... and it seems that the CSS media query is targeting those properties, and not the iframe width and height.

Comment: I could be understanding wrong. This example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp will create the iframe. The width and height is tiny (by default) and shows the mobile version of www.w3schools.com because the media queries hosted on w3schools make it that way. Is your media queries on the correct domain and do you have a width and height set for the iframe that falls under the media queries? If not, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you unless you're able to recreate it in a jsfiddle.

Comment: I have added two separate fiddles to clarify, one for the parent and one of the iframe

Comment: The problem with the query is that the iframe is not loaded from a device so the "min-device-width" won't work as it's not a device. If you change it to "min-width" and "max-width", leaving out the device, it should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: it works! thanks, but what if say I didn't have access to the "device" code. is there a way to "trick" the iframe into thinking it's a device? ... I know that it also involves modifying the headers (user agent) etc...

Comment: I haven't done something like that before but this might be what you're looking for http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp. I've posted my answer above if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the query is that the iframe is not loaded from a device so the "min-device-width" won't work as it's not a device. If you change it to "min-width" and "max-width", leaving out the device, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you

```js
var view=document.getElementById("view");

var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm');
view.appendChild(ifrm);
var ifrmId=document.getElementById("ifrm");
ifrmId.style.width="200px";
ifrmId.style.height="200px";
```

```html
<div id="view">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! but this is actually something that I already do. my problem is not the physical dimension of the iframe, iframe.document etc. is the iframe.screen object, which the media query is (I think) targeting...